# What is the time unit that strace uses when displaying time spent in syscalls?

Tags: linux, process, system-calls, strace, syscalls

When using the command `strace` with the flag `-T`, I would like to know what is the time unit used to display time spent in syscalls? I assume it should be in seconds, but I am not quite sure and it seems to be omitted from the manual.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

From [the source code](https://github.com/strace/strace/blob/3fedf07869e605841a70b4387f0b5ba44c073cf1/syscall.c#L927):

```
if (Tflag) {
    ts_sub(ts, ts, &tcp->etime);
    tprintf(" <%ld.%06ld>",
        (long) ts->tv_sec, (long) ts->tv_nsec / 1000);
}
```

This means that the time is shown in seconds, with microseconds (calculated from the nanosecond value) after the decimal point.

Answer (score 14):

If you run

```
strace -T  sleep 2
```

you will see

```
nanosleep({tv_sec=2, tv_nsec=0}, NULL)  = 0 <2.000230>
```

so it looks like the time spent is in seconds.

Answer (score 6):

If you run the command `strace` using the "flag -c" it will show you a table and the time is reported in **seconds**:

```
strace -c -p 3569 # 3569 is PID
strace: Process 3569 attached
^Cstrace: Process 3569 detached
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
99.73    0.016000           8      1971           poll
0.16    0.000025           0       509        75 futex
0.06    0.000010           0      1985      1966 recvmsg
0.06    0.000009           0      2336           mprotect
0.00    0.000000           0       478           read
0.00    0.000000           0        13           write
0.00    0.000000           0        29           mmap
0.00    0.000000           0         9           munmap
0.00    0.000000           0        18           writev
0.00    0.000000           0       351           madvise
0.00    0.000000           0         1           restart_syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
100.00    0.016044                  7700      2041 total
```

[from strace's man](https://linux.die.net/man/1/strace)

> -c
>
> Count time, calls, and errors for each system call and report a
>   summary on program exit. On Linux, this attempts to show system time
>   (CPU time spent running in the kernel) independent of wall clock time.
>   If -c is used with -f or -F (below), only aggregate totals for all
>   traced processes are kept.

Answer (score 0):

This can be seen from strace summary. e.g.:

```
$ strace -ce trace=write -p $(pidof app)
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
100.00    0.061558          17      3544           write
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
100.00    0.061558                  3544           total
```

- total time of write syscall = 0.061558 sec. or 0.061558*1000000 =
  61558 microseconds(usec)
- usec/calls = 61558 usec / 3544 calls =
  17.778